# Insert substring into character object in R

Tags: r, string

I'm manipulating a regression table produced by the `stargazer` package, which creates a table and stores it as a character object of length greater than 1 (naturally).

I would like to manipulate that character object by inserting some information about the model (e.g. grouping some variables for more information to the reader). Ultimately, it's a process of inserting multiple "rows" of characters/strings into an existing character object.

Here's a minimal working example.

```
thislittle <- c("this", "little", "to", "the", "market")
piggywent <- c("piggy", "went")
```

I would like to insert `piggywent` into `thislittle` to get this `complete` object.

```
> complete
[1] "this"   "little" "piggy"  "went"   "to"     "the"    "market"
```

For my specific purposes (beyond this minimal working example), I need to specify the exact element (here: the second) after which to insert this other character object.

Here's where I confess that this is probably a simple task but I'm completely unaccustomed to manipulating strings and character objects in R. I'm also unfamiliar with the terminology, which made searches fruitless. I've figured out how to overwrite some rows, but that's about it.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `c(thislittle[1:2], piggywent, thislittle[3:5])
[1] "this"   "little" "piggy"  "went"   "to"     "the"    "market"`?

Comment: `c(thislittle[a <- 1:2], piggywent, thislittle[-a])` is a wee bit shorter and avoids having to know the full length :)

Comment: Both work, but @Therkel's approach is nicely generalizable. That's nice for the job I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defining your index of the first bit of `thislittle`, you can remove these indexes when you append the rest of the vector with the minus operator. This can naturally be done in a seperate line before if it is more complex.

```
c(thislittle[a <- 1:2], piggywent, thislittle[-a])
# [1] "this"   "little" "piggy"  "went"   "to"     "the"    "market"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mySplit=which(thislittle=="little")
myl=length(thislittle)  

littleHead= thislittle[1:mySplit]  
littleTail= thislittle[(mySplit+1):myl]  
complete=append(littleHead, append(piggywent, littleTail))  

Hope it helps
```

Comment: `littleTail` can be simplified to `littleTail= thislittle[-(1:mySplit)]`. Then you don't need `myl`.